# jquery/javascript missing ) after formal parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Hi there I have this code:

```
function getFullnameDetails(mainHeight,upperstyle,type=''){
    setTimeout(function(){fullnameCenter(mainHeight,upperstyle,type='')},2000);
}
function fullnameCenter(mainHeight,upperstyle,type=''){
    var distOfMainAndUpper = mainHeight - upperstyle;
    var mainHalfHeight = mainHeight/2;
    var imageHeight = jQuery("img[rel='fullname']").height(); //there is a delay
    var imageHalfHeight = imageHeight/2;
    var fromImageTopToMainHalf = mainHalfHeight - imageHeight;
    var position = imageHalfHeight+fromImageTopToMainHalf-distOfMainAndUpper;
    if(type == 'big'){ jQuery("#temp .test1").css("bottom",position+"px"); }
    else { jQuery(".test1").css("bottom",position+"px"); }


}
```

It says that I'm missing ) after formal parameters.
This happens on this line:

```
function getFullnameDetails(mainHeight,upperstyle,type=''){ //IT HAPPENS HERE! :)
    setTimeout(function(){fullnameCenter(mainHeight,upperstyle,type='')},2000);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Javascript does not support default function parameter values.

You can do things like this (but be wary of unintended 'falsey' values):

```
function getFullnameDetails(mainHeight,upperstyle,type){
  type = type || ''; // if type is 'falsey' (null, undefined, empty string) assign ''
  //...
}
```

Comment: Instead, where you can, exploit short circuit evaluation with `arg = arg || 'default value';`.

Comment: @Elson Solano: I posted a solution which works even when 'falsey' values are used, which may help you.

Answer (score 3):

As other answers have pointed out, JavaScript doesn't support default values in the function parameters. However, as also pointed out in the other solutions, using an inline `||` won't work when falsey values are passed (eg `null`, `0`, `''`, `NaN`, `false`). A better solution is to check to see if the argument is undefined:

`type = typeof(type) !== 'undefined' ? type : '';`

or, more generally:

`argument_name = typeof(argument_name) !== 'undefined' ? argument_name : default_value;`

Of course, this means that passing `undefined` to a function will mean that the default value is used instead - but that should be pretty uncommon.

Comment: Huh? Using inline `||` _does_ work (with strings) when falsey values are passed...? `undefined` is logically false. The thing you have to be careful of is e.g. boolean and integer arguments, where a value of `false` or `0` (which you may _want_ to pass) would be evaluated as false. With a string parameter that doesn't matter.

Comment: `||` will work with strings, but only when the default value you want to assign is `''` - if you wanted some other default value, but wanted to be able to pass in `''`, then `||` would break. In my opinion, the `!== 'undefined'` approach is safer, because you don't need to ensure that the correct type is passed, and there's no chance of unexpected weirdness if someone copies the pattern elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to use like a default parameter or something?

type=''

That is not valid -- you can't have an equal sign in the parameter list of a function like that.

Comment: @Joseph: Your example shows the assignment expression among the *arguments*, not in the list of *parameters*.

Comment: @patrickdw ah I see. misunderstood what was going on. :P  Thanks for the correction!